# How to set config ,setup backup & restart Redis Stack Server in Linux

Tags: linux, redis-cluster, redis-stack-server

I have used Redis Server earlier now migrating to Redis Stack Server for enabling searching in redis database. I have followed [redis stack documentation](https://redis.io/docs/stack/get-started/install/linux/) but how to configure redis config, backup & restart is not mention anywhere in Ubuntu Server. Please Guide me how can i restart and set up config for Redis Stack Server